# Javascript (angularJS): filter by multiple field

Tags: javascript, angularjs, filter

For example i have such list (which i use with ng-repeat):

```
var myList = [
  {id: 1, name: 'Peter Ollison', type: 'Driver', status: 'Working'},
  {id: 2, name: 'Maya Nameson', type: 'Manager', status: 'Not'},
  {id: 3, name: 'Iki Jonny', type: 'Driver', status: 'Paused'},
  {id: 4, name: 'Nikolay Ivanov', type: 'Manager', status: 'Working'},
  {id: 5, name: 'Nikolay Ivanov', type: 'Sales manager', status: 'Not'},
  {id: 6, name: 'Scotty Deperson', type: 'Boss', status: 'Working'},
]
```

and i have filter arrays:

```
nameFilter: ['Peter Ollison', 'Nikolay Ivanov']
typeFilter: ['Manager', 'Driver']
statusFilter: ['Working']
```

how is it possible in filter function to combain all this filters? And to return only such items from the list, which are equal to filter arrays? BUT!!! I can have:

> filter only by name, or only by type, or 2 fields, or all of them

how is it possible to filter my list?

for example if i filter by 3 filter arrays in one time i should get as result:

```
[{id: 1, name: 'Peter Ollison', type: 'Driver', status: 'Working'},
{id: 4, name: 'Nikolay Ivanov', type: 'Manager', status: 'Working'}]
```

now i can filter only by one value in controller, and i got stucked with multiple fields filters((

Comment: Please share your code.

Comment: @Abhijeet http://pastebin.com/L3jXWTDy

Comment: You want to filter by matching at the same time any of the values per property? So the name may be peter or nikolay, and type may be manager or driver and status must be working?

Comment: @LeonardoLana yes

Comment: Give it a try http://pastebin.com/qbH9HCHi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$scope.showIssueItem = function (item) {
  var resultAssigneeCount = 0,
      resultTypeCount = 0,
      resultStatusCount = 0;

  if ($scope.nameFilterArr.length > 0) {
    angular.forEach($scope.nameFilterArr, function(value) {
      if (item.name === value) {
        resultAssigneeCount++;
      }
    });
  }else{
       resultAssigneeCount = 1;
  }

  if ($scope.typeFilterArr.length > 0) {
    angular.forEach($scope.typeFilterArr, function(value) {
      if (item.type === value) {
        resultTypeCount++;
      }
    });
  }else{
       resultTypeCount = 1;
  }

  if ($scope.statusFilterArr.length > 0) {
    angular.forEach($scope.statusFilterArr, function(value) {
      if (item.status === value) {
        resultStatusCount++;
      }
    });
  }else{
       resultStatusCount = 1;
  }

  return resultAssigneeCount>0 && resultTypeCount>0 && resultStatusCount>0;
};
```

Comment: if i have resultStatusCount === [], it won't output anything

Answer (score 0):

```
function contains(a, obj) {
    var i = a.length;
    while (i--) {
       if (a[i] === obj) {
           return true;
       }
    }
    return false;
}

$scope.showItemOrNot = function (item) {

          var match = [];
          var filters = [ {
             attr : 'assignee',
             source : $scope.assigneeFilterArr
            },
            {
                attr : 'type',
                source : $scope.typeFilterArr
            },
            {
                attr : 'status',
                source : $scope.statusFilterArr
            }
            ];

          for(var x in filters) {
              if(filters[x].source.length > 0) {
                match.push(contains(filters[x].source,item[filters[x].attr]));
              }
          }

          return !contains(match,false);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Using nested `Array.protoype.filter()`'s

```
var filterProps =  ['name','type','status'];

var filteredData = myList.filter(function(item){
  return  filterProps.filter(function(prop){
    var filter = filters[prop +'Filter'];   
    return !filter || !filter.length ||  filter.indexOf(item[prop]) >-1;
  }).length === filterProps.length;
})
```

```js
var myList = [
  {id: 1, name: 'Peter Ollison', type: 'Driver', status: 'Working'},
  {id: 2, name: 'Maya Nameson', type: 'Manager', status: 'Not'},
  {id: 3, name: 'Iki Jonny', type: 'Driver', status: 'Paused'},
  {id: 4, name: 'Nikolay Ivanov', type: 'Manager', status: 'Working'},
  {id: 5, name: 'Nikolay Ivanov', type: 'Sales manager', status: 'Not'},
  {id: 6, name: 'Scotty Deperson', type: 'Boss', status: 'Working'},
]

var filters = {
  nameFilter: ['Peter Ollison', 'Nikolay Ivanov'],
  typeFilter: ['Manager', 'Driver'],
  statusFilter: ['Working']

}
    
var filteredData = myList.filter(function(item){
  var filterProps =  ['name','type','status']
  return  filterProps.filter(function(prop){
    var filter = filters[prop +'Filter'];   
    return !filter || !filter.length ||  filter.indexOf(item[prop]) >-1;
  }).length===filterProps.length;
});

console.log(filteredData)
```